# Migration of database in MVC .net code first approach when connection string is changed on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Migration of database  in MVC .net **code first approach** when connection string is changed on run time.

I have dedicated database for every user and user is connected to his database on run-time. 
Now, when I have 100 users there will be 100 databases.
Now I have change in a column, then I want to reflect that column change in all the databases.
How I can update/migrate database on runtime. 
Meaning If there is any change in POCO classes it will automatically detect it and update/migrate database when it is connected.

Comment: tried package manager console?

Comment: migrations are essentially automatic no matter how many tenants you have.

Comment: @Dinav:  Package manager is for only to migrate database for default database. But my connectionstring comes from database ie on run time. So on runtime I can only know which database to update.